# Double Click in R-shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I had a small questions. I have tried researching this a lot but I have had no luck. Is there a way R-shiny has to capture a double click on an element like a button.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The key is to detect the `dblclick` event on the client side (i.e. ui), and then invoke `Shiny.onInputChange` to update the value of an R variable, which can then be picked up by the server.

Here is what happens when the button is double clicked.

1. The value is incremented by 1
2. The incremented value is used to update the variable `x`.
3. The server detects change in `x`
4. The server updates the `textOutput`.

> ```
> library(shiny)
>
> ui = bootstrapPage(
>   tags$button(id = 'mybutton', 'button', class='btn btn-primary', value = 0),
>   textOutput('x'),
>   # when button is double clicked increase the value by one
>   # and update the input variable x
>   tags$script("
>     $('#mybutton').on('dblclick', function(){
>       var val = +this.value
>       this.value = val + 1
>       Shiny.onInputChange('x', this.value)
>       console.log(this.value)
>     })  
>   ")
> )
>
> server = function(input, output, session){
>   output$x <- renderText({
>     input$x
>   })
> }
>
> runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my answer based on the comment below. Here I used a threshold of time difference of 0.2 seconds to differentiate between a double clock and a regular click. I used slightly different approach in My App. I simply check how many times the button has been pressed by checking if its divisible by 2 or not.

```
library(shiny)
t1 <<- Sys.time()

ui =fluidPage(
  actionButton("my_button", "Dont Touch it!"),
  mainPanel(textOutput("x"))
)
server = function(input, output, session){
  my_data <- reactive({  
    if(input$my_button == 0)
    {
      return()
    }

    if(input$my_button%%2!=0)
    {     
      t1 <<- Sys.time()
    }  
    if(input$my_button%%2==0 & (Sys.time() - t1 <= 0.2))
    {     
      "You pushed the button twice!"
    }  
  }) 
  output$x <- renderText({my_data()})
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: AFAIK two single clicks are NOT equivalent to a double click.

Comment: @Ramnath I've updated my answer to include the time threshold of the "double click"